# CASE WHEN SQL gives error

Tags: sql

I get an error 'syntax error in from clause' when I try to run my case when:

```
select ewc_code, shortclass as EWCDesc, tonnage as tonnes, 
       waste_fate as fate, 'deposit wpa' as destination 
from hwi
CASE waste_fate
    WHEN 'Transfer (r)' THEN 'Transfer'
    When 'Transfer (d)' then 'transfer'
else waste_fate
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the `CASE` should be inside your query, most likely in the `SELECT` clause.

Secondly you are missing the `END` in your `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT ewc_code, shortclass as EWCDesc, tonnage as tonnes, waste_fate as fate,
  'deposit wpa' as destination,
  CASE waste_fate
    WHEN 'Transfer (r)' THEN 'Transfer'
    WHEN 'Transfer (d)' THEN 'transfer'
    ELSE waste_fate
  END
FROM hwi
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing an `END`:

```
CASE  WHEN waste_fate = 'Transfer (r)' THEN 'Transfer' 
      WHEN waste_fate = 'Transfer (d)' THEN 'transfer' 
      ELSE waste_fate END
```

And this returns a scalar that you need to think what do you want to do with.
Most chances is, that you wanted to add it to your `SELECT` clause and not your `FROM` clause.

Comment: Adding the end won't solve the issue. If you pay attention the error is in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @MostyMostacho - You were downvoted for no reason but don't get angry at me. You can use `CASE` statement in the FROM clause. And answer doesn't have to solve everything in the question - the OP does! This is something not nice to say...

Comment: Yosi, you can't have a case in there that references a field

Comment: That is the `WHERE` clause, Yosi. The `FROM` clause is different from the `WHERE` clause. Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c2788/1